# How to get JSON Data depending on other data values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, protractor

My Json is like this:

```
[    
 {"isoCode":"BW","name":"Botswana ","CashOut":"Y","BankOut":"","MMT":null},
 {"isoCode":"BR","name":"Brazil ","CashOut":"Y","BankOut":"Y","MMT":null},
 {"isoCode":"BG","name":"Bulgaria ","CashOut":"Y","BankOut":"Y","MMT":"Y"},
 {"isoCode":"BF","name":"Burkina Faso","CashOut":"Y","BankOut":"","MMT":null},
 {"isoCode":"BI","name":"Burundi","CashOut":"","BankOut":"","MMT":"Y"},
 {"isoCode":"KH","name":"Cambodia","CashOut":"Y","BankOut":"","MMT":null}
]
```

I want all the names which have BankOut value as "Y" into an array using JavaScript, in order to use those names in my protractor automation.

Comment: You have an `array`, not `JSON`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use filter method of array. It takes function as it argument. And runs it against each element of array. If function returns true (or other truthy value) then that element stays in newly created array.

```js
var list =[    {"isoCode":"BW","name":"Botswana ","CashOut":"Y","BankOut":"","MMT":null},
 {"isoCode":"BR","name":"Brazil ","CashOut":"Y","BankOut":"Y","MMT":null},
 {"isoCode":"BG","name":"Bulgaria ","CashOut":"Y","BankOut":"Y","MMT":"Y"},
 {"isoCode":"BF","name":"Burkina Faso ",   "CashOut":"Y","BankOut":"","MMT":null},
 {"isoCode":"BI","name":"Burundi","CashOut":"","BankOut":"","MMT":"Y"},
 {"isoCode":"KH","name":"Cambodia","CashOut":"Y","BankOut":"","MMT":null}
 ];

var onlyBankOutY = list.filter(function (item) {
  return item.BankOut === 'Y';
});

document.body.innerHTML = onlyBankOutY.map(function (item) {
  return JSON.stringify(item);
}).join('<br>');
```

Comment: Thank you @lazarev for the response, it worked for me. Thank you sielakos for the solution, in my case I want only elements but I'll use this in my future projects.

Comment: I would not recommend using forEach for doing something that filter was created for. It is asking for mistakes in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list =[
  {"isoCode":"BW","name":"Botswana ","CashOut":"Y","BankOut":"","MMT":null},
  {"isoCode":"BR","name":"Brazil ","CashOut":"Y","BankOut":"Y","MMT":null},
  {"isoCode":"BG","name":"Bulgaria ","CashOut":"Y","BankOut":"Y","MMT":"Y"},
  {"isoCode":"BF","name":"Burkina Faso ",   "CashOut":"Y","BankOut":"","MMT":null},           {"isoCode":"BI","name":"Burundi","CashOut":"","BankOut":"","MMT":"Y"},
  {"isoCode":"KH","name":"Cambodia","CashOut":"Y","BankOut":"","MMT":null}
];

var names = [];
list.forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.BankOut === 'Y') {
    names.push(el.name)
  }
})
```